# html jquery click function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery 1.10.2 but this code is not working:

```
$("#hbox99").click(function(e) {
    var loginoutbox = document.getElementById("cbox");

    fromtop = cbox.style.bottom;

    if(fromtop=="0px")  {
        $("#cbox").css('bottom','-365');}
    else{
        $("#cbox").css('bottom','0');}
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="data" id="cbox">
<div class="databox" id="hbox99"><div class="headtxt">Text</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the entire code and HTML? You may simply be missing a DOM ready handler around your code, but who can tell? :)

Comment: By not working you mean...? What is it supposed to do and what does it do instead? Error messages? Have you done any basic debugging (value of `fromtop` etc)?

Comment: I don't know if `cbox` is a Javascript thing, but you assigned your `getElementById` to a variable you don't use. Did you want to use it?

Comment: But where is your JavaScript called? Are you sure you are loading your `HTML` items first before you call your JavaScript? Also is this your entire JavaScript, where is `cbox` defined? @Zhouster It's not.

Comment: it that is reason for error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code (both HTML and JavaScript), but it *looks* like you have a null reference exception in that you are creating the variable "loginoutbox", but then attempting to reference the style property of a object called "cbox".

You *probably* want to do this-

```
$("#hbox99").click(function(e) {
   var loginOutBox = document.getElementById("cbox"), fromTop = loginOutBox.style.bottom;

   if (fromTop === "0px") {
      $("#cbox").css('bottom',-365);
   }
   else {
      $("#cbox").css('bottom',0);
   }
});
```

As well as attempting to fix the code, I've assigned "fromTop" to a variable (otherwise it becomes an implicit variable), used camel case for the variable names to improve readability and used the (generally recommended) triple equals equality operator (which checks **both** type and value - a good habit to get into). I've also changed your "bottom" values from strings (surrounded by quotes) to integers, which if I remember correctly will be converted to pixels by jQuery for you.

If it is a fixed value rather than one which is calculated, then it may well be worth writing as a string but with the unit, e.g. '-365px'.

Comment: It would also be worth spending some time looking at the developer tools of your chosen browser(s) as these would have most likely told you the error without resorting to asking a question on StackOverflow. Nonetheless, welcome and I hope you enjoy learning JavaScript.